# Cascading chain transitions with promises in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

As you can see on this [site](http://autocustos.info/XX), between form parts, several transitions occur in chain on the several `div` elements.

But the transitions must be executed in chain, i.e. the next transition just advances when the previous transitions for *all* its corresponding elements are complete. Thus one needs to use `.promise().done()`

An example:

```
$("#p1").slideUp("slow", function(){
    $("#description").
        html(DescriptionHTML).
        slideDown("fast", function(){
            $("#div1, #div3").
                hide().
                promise().
                done(function(){
                    $("#div1_td, #div3_td").
                        show().
                        promise().
                        done(function(){
                            $("#p2").
                                slideDown("slow", function(){
                                    $("#div1, #div3").
                                        show("slow").
                                        promise().
                                        done(function(){  
                                            scrollPage();
                                    });
                            });
                        });
                });
            });          
        });
```

Is there any user friendly shortcut for the above code?
Something like:

```
.SyncChain({
    step1: function(){
            $("#p1").slideUp("slow");
        },
    step2: function(){
            $("#description").html(DescriptionHTML).slideDown("fast");
        },
    step3: function(){
            $("#div1, #div3").hide();
        },  
    step4: function(){
            $("#div1_td, #div3_td").show();
        },
    step5: function(){
            $("#p1").slideDown("slow");
        },
    step6: function(){
            $("#div1, #div3").show("slow").
        }
});
```

Comment: I thought, Page height shrink and expand in not the Good User Experience, Better you will use fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: @RaviDelixan, depends on the effects you'd like to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, you have a special function called generator.

This function allows to call a yield  statement than interrupts execution of the function until it is called again.

This allows to write async functions in a sync looking way

more or less, you could write something like

```js
var myfunc;

function* animation() {
  yield $("#elem1").slideUp(5000, myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 1');

  yield $("#elem2").slideUp(5000, myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 2');

  yield $("#elem3, #elem4").each(function(n) {
    $(this).fadeOut(5000 * (n + 1));
  }).promise().done(myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 3');

  yield $("#elem3, #elem4").each(function(n) {
    $(this).fadeIn(5000 * (n + 1));
  }).promise().done(myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 4');
  yield $("#elem2").slideDown(5000, myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 5');
  yield $("#elem1").slideDown(5000, myfunc);

  $('#info').html('step 6');

}

function run() {
  var gen = animation();
  myfunc = function() {
    gen.next();
  };
  myfunc();
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 85px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="run()">RUN</button>
<div id="elem1">1</div>
<div id="elem2">2</div>
<div id="elem3">3</div>
<div id="elem4">4</div>
<div id="elem5">5</div>
<span id="info"></span>
```

The **generator** function animation returns an generator object, that is assigned to myfunc.

Then, the completion functions to call are always the same function.

After calling a method that will be completed asynchronously, set a yield to stop the function until it is called again.

Comment: Thank you. I checked [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) the compatibility of `yield` function for ES6. It seems IE11 doesn't run it.

Comment: why in the last two lines of the *animation function you have in the callback the function `myfunc` and the function's returning value `myfunc()` ? Thank you

Comment: Unluckily, IE11 doesn't run it. Luckily, you can transpile this code with Babel to the previous version of JavaScript, and it will run in IE >= 9. In my previous version, I did a mistake with my use of myfunc. Now there is a working version. The callback will always be a wrapper around the next() function of the generator object.